# Power Query Nested Table to String

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery

I have an xml that i'm processing and my output is the below image:

[image: Print1]

The problem is that i get 2 columns and one has a nested table inside and the other one just the value.

My output need to be something like this:

[image: Print2]

Can anybody help?

Comment: Is there a way we can reproduce this?

Comment: Please [edit] the additional information into your question

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a new custom column like this:

```
= Table.AddColumn(PreviousStepNameHere, "FREQ Expanded",
      each if Value.Type([FREQ]) = Value.Type("text") then [FREQ]
           else Table.ToList([FREQ]))
```

And then expand that new column using this code:

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"FREQ Expanded",
      each if Value.Type(_) = Value.Type("text") then _
           else Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text})
```

If your type for non-tables is something else, then adjust accordingly.