# merge rows with group by power query

Tags: excel, group-by, powerbi

im trying to merge rows values based on equal categories.
for example the following table:

[image]

i want to group by the values from column "note" based on the "code" column so the table will look as follow:

[image]

is there a way i can do it with power query build in options or it must be function I build my own?

thanks!

Comment: You can achieve this in a pivottable, using a DAX measure (CONCATENATEX). Have a look at my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53171336/how-to-transpose-all-subfields-in-front-of-the-parent-field-of-a-pivot-table-in/53172624#53172624) question

Comment: @Marco Vos thanks! exactly what i needed!

Comment: I've posted how to do this in the query editor before too. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708114/power-query-data-transformation-from-a-single-column-to-a-whole-table/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49781281/power-query-nested-table-to-string/).

Answer (score 0):

To do this in the query editor, you can Group By the `code` column and then modify the aggregator to use `Text.Combine` to do the concatenation on the `note` column.

I've explained this in more detail in the middle step of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708114/power-query-data-transformation-from-a-single-column-to-a-whole-table/52726083#52726083).